# Video for IE9 not working until I change the values in the developer tool

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
    <source src="audiovisual/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="audiovisual/video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But the video is not showing in IE9

It is amazing that when I enter into the developer tool (pressing key F12) and change the value for the width or the height it appears immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was hard to find it.

I move the code of the video to the beginning of the body, and it works. So I realized that it was a problem of the container of this element.

I start changing the css of the container and when I remove `display:hidden;` it shows the video (but I need the container to start hidden)

What I did was to change the previous code to `width:0px; overflow:hidden;` so when I change the width of the container (with jQuery) it works now the video.

Thanks.